# Jar file does not work in IDE, but works in terminal

Tags: java, netbeans

I am experiencing a problem with netbeans 8.0. If I run my project on the terminal, it runs sucessfully. But, in netbeans IDE I get the error: `Could not find main class`.

In the terminal i run `"java -jar "/Users/diogoaleixo/Desktop/Computação grafica/OlaMundo2D/dist/OlaMundo2D.jar"`.

I have already defined the main class in the properties of the project.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Are you trying to run a jar with NetBeans ?

Comment: In the command line yes. The .jar file aggregate all the files in the project isn´t it? But the problem is in the netBeans i click "run" to run the project and gives me the could not find main class

Comment: I am using macricks osX.